# Is there any way to know which floor you are building before it is built?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

In Tiny Death Star, floors under construction are only identified by their category (e.g. Service, Residential, Retail etc.) Is there any way to tell what *specific* level is currently under construction? For example, if I build a Residential level, can I tell if it is going to be Dagobah Apts. before construction is complete? If so, how?

Comment: @Han In this question, are you wondering if you can figure out what the building is (specific floor) or what type of building (which category) it is before it is done.

Comment: @Turtleweezard, good edit!

Comment: D'awww :3 thanks much. Now If only I could get Han to accept my answer...

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can tell ahead of time what floor is currently being built. To do this:

1. Open up the **Menu** in the bottom-right corner.
   [image]
2. Then go to the **Album**.
   [image]
3. Choose the category of floor currently under construction from the tabs at the top.
   [image]

   *All unlocked floors*,including ones still under construction, will be displayed, so look for an unlocked floor that you don't recognize. That's your new floor!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know what floor is in the process of being constructed before it is finished, you can typically tell by going to the Floors screen under the menu. Since you have already selected the type of floor to be constructed, go to that tab (for example, the Food tab) and look for an unlocked floor that you don't already have in use.